# Numpy: Temporary copy during assignment

Tags: numpy

Consider the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

buf = np.full(10, True)
A = np.asarray([1,2,3])

buf[:3] = A!=A
```

In the last statement, will there be a temporary object created to hold the value of the expression `A!=A` which would subsequently be copied into `buf` or will the copy be elided?

Side note: I am aware of `numpy.not_equal` which can be passed an `out` argument to store the result. However, I am working with structured arrays and for some reasons that method is throwing the following error:

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
```

I am using Numpy 1.12.

Comment: Yes, there will be temporary array, There's evwn one in a `+=` expression.  And the use of an `out` parameter doesn't bypass it either.

Comment: In v 14, `A!=A` returns record-wise comparison, not the warning.

Comment: @hpaulj It does so in 1.12 as well. The warning is for the case of `numpy.not_equal`. And there's no output either.